# programmatically customize eclipse project explorer

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an eclipse plugin and i need to programmatically adjust the project explorer.

I want to deselect "content extensions" in the project explorer. Doing this manually is very simple, it is described in the following [post](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-red-x-icon-didnt-display-on-project-explorer/). But how to do this programmatically?

EDIT:
I can now see if its active or not but i still cant find the api to change this

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IViewPart view = page.findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);                

ProjectExplorer expl = (ProjectExplorer) page
                    .findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
INavigatorContentService content = expl.getNavigatorContentService();
content.isActive(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done Using the actication service from the content service

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();                
ProjectExplorer expl = (ProjectExplorer) page
                    .findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);             
INavigatorContentService content = expl.getNavigatorContentService();               
content.getActivationService().deactivateExtensions(new String[] {ID}, false);
```